# Value of $a$ for function to admit a primitive

Tags: calculus

The function is $a$ for $x=0$ and $\sin^2\left(\frac1x\right)$ for any other $x$. The answer is supposed to be $\frac12$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Please explain what you mean y primitive.

Comment: I mean that the function is primitivable

Comment: I guess you mean there is a continuous function $F$ such that $F'(x)=\sin^2(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$, and $ F'(0)=a.$ Right ?

Comment: Yes, that s what I mean

Comment: "I mean that the function is primitivable". You must be joking. That does not answer the question at all, just changes it with a more obscure name.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think the notion is a French cliche. See https://les-mathematiques.net/vanilla/index.php?p=/discussion/2105286/f-primitivable-implique-f-primitivable

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(0)=0$ and
$$F(x)=\int\limits_0^x\sin^2(t^{-1})\,dt=\int\limits_{x^{-1}}^\infty {\sin^2 u\over u^2}\,du,\quad x\neq 0$$  We have $F(-x)=-F(x),$ thus it suffices to restrict analysis to $x\ge 0.$ For $x>0$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus we get
$$F'(x)=\sin^2(x^{-1})$$
We will make use of the second expression to determine $F_+'(0).$
For $x>0$ we have
$${F(x)-F(0)\over x}={1\over x} \int\limits_{x^{-1}}^\infty {\sin^2 u\over u^2}\,du$$
Substitute $y=x^{-1}.$ Then
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+ }{F(x)-F(0)\over x}= \lim_{y\to +\infty} y\int\limits_{y}^\infty {\sin^2 u\over u^2}\,du$$
Applying $2\sin^2u=1-\cos(2u)$ and integration by parts gives
$$\displaylines{\int\limits_{y}^\infty {\sin^2 u\over u^2}\,du= {1\over 2}\int\limits_{y}^\infty {1\over u^2}\,du-{1\over 2}\int\limits_{y}^\infty {\cos(2u)\over u^2}\,du\\ =
{1\over 2y}+{1\over 4}{\sin(2y)\over y^2}-{1\over 2}\int\limits_y^\infty {\sin(2u)\over u^3}\,du}$$
Next
$$\int\limits_y^\infty {|\sin(2u)|\over u^3}\,du\le \int\limits_y^\infty {1\over u^3}\,du={1\over 2y^2}$$ Therefore
$$y\int\limits_{y}^\infty {\sin^2 u\over u^2}\,du={1\over 2}+O(y^{-1})$$
This implies $F'_+(0)={1\over 2}.$ As the function $F$ is odd we get $F'_-(0)={1\over 2}.$